# How can I execute a terminal command when opening IntelliJ Project?

Tags: intellij-idea, automation, ide, vagrant, local

Not even sure if this possible with IntelliJ but I'd like to tie the `vagrant up` command to run automatically when I open an IntelliJ project. I've scoured the settings but haven't been able to find anything that gives me this functionality.

Comment: This feature can be implemented as a plug-in for IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: you could do the other way around, so opening IntelliJ when you run a vagrant up command; otherwise you can look https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207277809-Run-terminal-command-on-project-startup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a plugin.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/plugin-development-guidelines.html

Define an application component in the plugin.xml

```
<application-components>
  <component>
    <implementation-class>com.steve.plugins.recentprojects.RecentProjects</implementation-class>
  </component>
</application-components>
```

And then you implement `ApplicationComponent`, which defines these methods in a parent interface:

```
public interface BaseComponent extends com.intellij.openapi.components.NamedComponent {
    default void initComponent() { /* compiled code */ }
    default void disposeComponent() { /* compiled code */ }
}
```

It seems like `initComponent()` can be a nice place to insert a function to start vagrant.

Alternatively... externalise the startup, write a script that starts vagrant and then starts intellij...

Comment: Thak you for this. I will attempt to go the plugin route